# Помогите не работает тернарный-оператор

Tags: c, тернарный-оператор

```
long double fact(int value)
{
    value == 1 ? return 1 ;
    return value * fact(value - 1);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну во-первых здесь нет тернарного оператора (законченного), а во-вторых даже если бы он и был, писать return внутри выражения всё равно бы никто не позволил

Comment: Синтаксис тернарного оператора:  условие ? выражение1 : выражение2

Comment: `return value == 1? 1: value * fact(value - 1);`

Comment: Тернарный - от слова "три" (операнда).

Comment: тут наверно имеет смысл сделать `value <= 1`, а то прилетит  `-1` или `0` и уже будет не совсем удачно =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синтаксис тернарного оператора следующий:

> ```
> conditional-expression:
>     logical-OR-expression
>     logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
> ```

Тернарный оператор в качесте операндов принимает **выражения** ([**expressions**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions)), вы же пытаетесь передать в него [**statements**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements) `return 1` и `return value * fact(value - 1)`<sup>1</sup>.

В вашем случае можно поступить следующим образом:

```
return value == 1 ? 1 : value * fact(value - 1);
```

Если объяснять *очень* грубо и «на пальцах», то statement — это команда, которая исполняется, а expression — то, *над чем* исполняется эта команда. У вас в коде они перепутаны.

---

<sup>1. Вместо точки с запятой (`;`) после `return 1` должно быть двоеточие (`:`). Скорее всего, это просто опечатка.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, потому что вы его не написали - в нем двоеточние, а не точка с запятой, а во вторых, в нем должно быть *выражение*.

Так что напишите так:

```
long double fact(unsigned int value)
{ 
    return (value <= 1) ? 1 : value * fact(value - 1);
}
```

`unsigned int` - вы же не будете брать факториал от отрицательных чисел?